# Additional quantum states of the infinite square well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

The quantum states $\psi(x)$ of the infinite square well of width $a$ are given by

$$\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\Big(\frac{n \pi x}{a}\Big),\ n= 1,2,3, \dots$$

Now, I understand $n \neq 0$, as otherwise $\psi(x)$ is non-normalisable.

But, can't we get additional states for $n=-1,-2,-3,\dots$?

Of course, they have the same position probability densities and energy eigenvalues as the corresponding positive $n$ states, but still, don't they *exist* at all?

Comment: $\psi_{-n}(x)=-\psi_n(x)$, so they are the same quantum state. Remember quantum states are defined up a global phase.

Comment: Well, do we not rely on the negative sign on the wavefunction to distinguish between bosons and fermions?

For bosons and fermions, we might as well call these the same particle as the wavefunction differs by a phase factor ???

Comment: you are mixing things up. First of all, bosons/fermions only come into the story when you have two or more particles. Even then an *overall* phase does not matter, this is just a basic rule of quantum mechanics. Bosons/fermions is not distinguished by an overall sign, it's the relative sign between $\psi(x_1,x_2)$ and $\psi(x_2, x_1)$.

Comment: Just want to add that $n$ being an integer is to satisfy the boundary conditions $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=a$. It is not related to the normalizability of the wave functions.

Comment: "I understand n≠0, as otherwise ψ(x) is non-normalisable." For $n=0$, $\psi=0$ and the probability of finding the particle in the box would be zero. Obviously the probability of finding the particle in the box must be 1. So $n=0$ is not a real solution.

Comment: You might be interested in the related questions [Difference for boundary condition, particle in a box](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220554/difference-for-boundary-condition-particle-in-a-box) and [Why is n=0 allowed for a particle on a ring?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218258/why-is-n-0-allowed-for-a-particle-on-a-ring).